# Synonymize [this] and [self]?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, synonym-request

*Note: These tags should either be joined, if they're alright, or burninated, if they aren't. Right now I'm talking about joining them because I looked through [the burnination criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191) but it passes 2 and 4, so I'm not confident about burninating them. I don't like 'em much, but they might not be burninate-worthy.*

[self](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/self) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/this) are two *very* similar tags. They're pretty much literal synonyms, actually -- different programming langauges use one or the other for what are mostly identical purposes.

To prove how similar they are, take a glance at their tag wikis:

> Keyword that refers to the current class instance or object in many object-oriented programming languages.

and

> A keyword used in instance methods to refer to the object on which they are working.

They're so close to identical that in the time it took me to copy/paste and format, I forgot which was which. They're not meaningfully separate in the slightest -- at least, not with their current tag descriptions. Because of that, I propose that we either synonymize them or clarify how they're different.

The only problem is deciding which should be the master tag. I'm partial to `this` both because [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/this) has 2740 questions, compared to [self](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/self)'s meager 668 and because Wikipedia uses `this` over `self` for [their article on the subject](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_%28computer_programming%29). However, a case could probably be made for `self` as well.

If there are any other tags with the same meaning, consider them a part of this synonym request as well (and lemme know in a comment so I can add them in).

---

<sup>Incidentally, the 'related questions' were all totally useless -- all about *self*-answers or "Is *this*..." so I apologize if this is a duplicate.</sup>

Comment: Doesn't sound like a tag which should be burninated, imo. But `this` and `self` are very specific to the language (as far as which is used), so I'm not strongly in favor of a merge, and `this` has more questions because it is more common.

Comment: @Kevin The thing about language specificness is that we already have language tags for that, and enough languages use both `this` and `self` that it doesn't really add any new information.

Comment: There are even 34 questions that are tagged with both.

Comment: If so should we include `me` (VB)?

Comment: `this` doesn't even mean exactly the same thing in different languages. It certainly isn't a synonym with `self`. The tag info wikis can be fixed. Synonomizing keywords that aren't synonyms does not make sense for languages that don't have both keywords.

Comment: @James_Parsons I don't think there's a [tag:me] tag, though. If there is one, it might fit -- In that case, though, it's specifically for VB, so my main argument doesn't really hold.

Comment: @BilltheLizard My main point is that `this` and `self` are used over multiple languages, so they have to refer to the generic concept, rather than any specific implementation, so they end up meaning the same thing. If it was something like [java-this] or [ruby-self] then obviously they wouldn't be synonyms, but the only cross-language traits of `this` and `self` are identical (as far as I know). Of course, we could also split them into [java-this] and [c#-this] and [ruby-self] and [vb-me], but that seems a bit too specific.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

**No**, because:

1. [`this` in Javascript](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_%28computer_programming%29#JavaScript) (its most commonly associated tag) and [`self` in Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/This_%28computer_programming%29#Python) (likewise) are *not* synonyms; they are distinct in a number of important ways.
2. In PHP, `$this` and `self` are also [distinct concepts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151969/when-to-use-self-vs-this).
3. If one is made a synonym of the other, the "loser" would be automatically converted to the "winner", causing severe confusion for beginner programmers of languages which used the "losing" term.