# This tag is not [old] but it could make us [old]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

A new tag, [old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/old) was recently created for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73086141/dafny-using-old-keyword-in-post-condition-not-working). I think it is ambiguous and should be removed.

### [Burnination criteria](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate):

#### 1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

No, [old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/old) could mean anything. It could refer to legacy code, legacy systems, old concepts, calculating the age of something and apparently there is an `old` keyword in some language which was the reason for the tag's creation.

#### 2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

While keywords in languages and improving legacy code are on-topic, the concept of something being old is not.

#### 3. Does the tag add *any* meaningful information to the post?

No. The concept of something being `old` is so broad, it could mean anything.

#### 4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

Absolutely not. As stated previously, it could refer to legacy code, legacy systems, old concepts, dangling pointers/references, calculating the age of something and apparently there an `old` keyword.

### Other problems

The tag could possibly attract a lot of questions without giving any meaning to them.

### alternatives

If there were lots of questions regarding the `old`-keyword, we could rename the tag to something like [old-keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/old-keyword) or [dafny-old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dafny-old).

### Burn!

Let it burn before it spreads and we become [old](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/old) trying to remove it!

Comment: Do we have a precedent for making tags for keywords in languages, beyond widespread keywords/languages?

Comment: Does it make sense to create a burnination request for a tag with a single post though? Just edit it out to get rid of it.

Comment: @tripleee According to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/322335/do-i-need-to-ask-before-burninating-tiny-tags), yes. If I had information ok to do so for new tags with a single question, I would do so.

Comment: It doesn't need all phases of the burnination process but there are still the conditions "you have authoritativea knowledge of all technologies relevant to the tag;" (I don't have any knowledge about the programming language this is a keyword in) and "you have conferred with at least one other trusted community member;" in [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/324071).

Comment: Couldn't find a meta post, but I'll take the existence of [tag:this-keyword] as an indicator we probably do. There's also tags for visibility modifiers, and a number of others. Also seeing https://stackoverflow.com/q/64628903/6296561 that probably could have the tag, but [a number that involve it](https://www.ecosia.org/search?q=dafny%20old%20site%3Astackoverflow.com), which indicates it's an important keyword in the language. If there aren't any objections, I'd recommend renaming it to [old-keyword] (or maybe something else explicitly involving dafny to reduce abuse) instead of burning

Comment: ... not that `this` isn't wide-spread, but there's quite a few keyword tags on the site overall. [tag:this-keyword] just happens to be one where the base for ([tag:this], which I just noticed is an actual tag) wouldn't work out as a tag, which is very much applicable ere

Comment: We might also want to synonymize [this], [this-keyword] and [self] anyways but that's something for another post I guess.

Comment: Yep, but definitely a discussion for a different post. Feel free to write one :p

Comment: It seems like it [has already been declined](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/294335/synonymize-this-and-self).

Comment: That's just [this] and [self], not [this] and [this-keyword]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This tag isn't an example of a tag that could in any multiverse be useful to identify questions that I would be able to answer. I can know if a question may require ancient knowledge if it's using COBOL, Visual Basic, etc. but just because you tell me that it's old, whenever that means to you 1 month or 1 century, makes no difference to me if I don't know the technology being used. The concept itself is fluid and ambiguous, it doesn't mean to me what it means to you.

Tags are supposed to be useful for potential answerers identify questions that they would be capable of applying their expertise into answering, this tag doesn't achieve that minimum requirement. Just remove it.